# Geth Puppeth set Seaing Profit to 0

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, genesis, poa

I am creating a private blockchain network using GoEthereum. I am using `Clique` (to get the PoA protocol). Since I have predefined sealers/miners, I do not want to set any mining profit for them. But the way I created the genesis block (using `puppeth`), sealers get a fixed amount of `21000000000000` per transaction verification.

Is there any way to set it to 0?

My genesis block is:

```
{
  "config": {
    "chainId": 1900,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip150Block": 0,
    "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0,
    "byzantiumBlock": 0,
    "constantinopleBlock": 0,
    "petersburgBlock": 0,
    "istanbulBlock": 0,
    "clique": {
      "period": 7,
      "epoch": 30000
    }
  },
  "nonce": "0x0",
  "timestamp": "0x5fae646a",
  "extraData": "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000046ad11ac56be36862e0439d053eb87b060168c7a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "gasLimit": "0x47b760",
  "difficulty": "0x1",
  "mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "alloc": {
   ......  
   },
   "number": "0x0",
  "gasUsed": "0x0",
  "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
}
```